# swig - c++ to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, swig, v8

I'm trying to build a simple javascript module using swig from my cpp files. I ran alll the right commands but it seems like nothing is working. 
this is my `.h` file

```
#pragma once

class Die
{
public:
    Die();
    Die(int a);
    ~Die();
    int foo(int a) ;
    Die* getDie(int a);
    int myVar;
};
```

my `.cpp` file:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "example.h"
int Die::foo(int a) {

    std::cout << "foo: running fact from simple_ex" <<std::endl;
    return 1;
}

Die::Die(){}
Die::Die(int a){myVar = a;}
Die::~Die(){}
Die* Die::getDie(int a) {
    return new Die (a);
}
```

my `.i` file:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

my `binding.gyp` file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "example",
      "sources": ["example.cpp", "example_wrap.cxx" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed all the command from the `swig` docs.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-dev
sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-dev
swig -c++ -javascript -node example.i
node-gyp configure build
```

After I run the last commands i get all sorts of errors:

```
error: ‘NewSymbol’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
```

and many many more..
Any help will do.

Thanks!

Comment: Found a solution to this? I get all sorts of 'not a member', 'has no member' and 'was not declared' errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tried that example to learn this interface myself.
To help others who may stumble upon this here is an example how to work
with swig and js.

First we write the C++ class and its logic using the objectbased approach swig is learning us.

```
#pragma once

class Die
{
public:
    Die(int a);
    ~Die();
    int foo(int a);
    int myVar;
};

extern "C" 
{
    Die* getDie(int a);
}
```

The interesting thing here is we don't always create a new instance
but we use an external function to lend us a pointer to the class which can then used to import it in our Javascript. This is literally what swig is all about.

Here is the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "example.h"
int Die::foo(int a) 
{
    std::cout << "foo: running fact from simple_ex" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

Die::Die(int a)
{
    myVar = a;
}

Die::~Die()
{

}

extern "C" 
{

    Die* getDie(int a) 
    {
        return new Die(a);
    }

}
```

also here the function to get that said pointer is encapsulated in extern C
which is how we separate it from the other class implementation and also some help for the compiler.

The swig interface is the same as in the question. It is used to generate the wrap-file swig makes to give us a implemented interface between Javascript and our C++ library

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

this creates us the wrap-file using the following statement in terminal:

```
swig -c++ -javascript -node example.i
```

now we need some tools for Javascript to build this:

you need to install NodeJs and NPM to use the following things.

first we need a package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "SwigJS",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node index.js",
      "install": "node-gyp clean configure build"
      
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "nan": "^2.16.0",
      "node-gyp": "^9.0.0"
    }
}
```

this is important to let the build programm know some information about the package and its dependencies.

after that we create a file called "binding.gyp"

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "SwigJS",
      "sources": [ "example_wrap.cxx", "example.cpp" ],
      "include_dirs" : [ "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this hold information for our buildtarget and also towards nan.

to get this working we now need to create the .node file.
this is done by either using:

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

or using:

```
npm i
```

both does nearly the same as it appears to me. (correct me if i am wrong)

at last we now implement our Javascript and use the library there.
There are some more tricks to make the path on top to disappear so that
you could write just require("modulname") but thats actually to much for this example.

```
const Swigjs = require("./build/Release/SwigJS.node");

console.log("exports :", Swigjs); //show exports to see if we have a working library

die = Swigjs.getDie(5); //get the Class pointer

console.log("foo:" + die.foo(5)); //call a function from the class
```

I hope this helps to get a clear sight how swig and js work together